# XOR instruction not working as thought (Intel 8086)

Tags: memory, assembly, reverse-engineering, intel, xor

I am studying a topic of mine that I am fascinated with, reverse engineering. But I have run into a little speed bump. I know the bitwise operator **xor** and what it does to the bits but it doesnt seem to be working correctly when I watch it in process in the disassembler. The small segement of code I am dealing with is:

```
MOV EAX, 0040305D
XOR DWORD PTR [EAX], 1234567
```

Before the **xor** has taken place, the number that resides at the location *0040305D* is *1234* or *31323334* hexadecimal (It is represented as ASCII because it was taken from a user input and it firmly resides as *31323334* in memory). When I looked up a **xor** calculator on the internet to check to make sure I was doing everything alright on paper I got the result of the **xor** calculation as *30117653* hexadecimal. But when I run the operation in disassembler it replaced the memory location held in *EAX* with *56771035*.

What just happened? Am I missing something here? I checked the xor calculation on many calculators and I am not able to get the answer of *56771035*. Can someone give me a hand and tell me what I am doing wrong?

-Dan

Comment: The only explanation I see is that value at the address is not 31323334.

Comment: There must be something else going on. Your 30117653 appears to be correct assuming the 1234567 value is in hex and the original dword value is 31323334h.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numbers displayed are all in hex and you have forgotten to use proper endianness. If the user input was ascii `1234` that means the memory contains the bytes `31 32 33 34`. Since x86 is little endian, the operand `1234567` is byte sequence `67 45 23 01`. Performing the `xor` operation we get the byte sequence `56 77 10 35` which is what you see.

Comment: beat me to it, exactly that +1

Comment: ah! Thank you! This little endian is hard to get use to but through the stumbles ill start thinking like it. Thank you again!

Comment: @Jester Wait quick question why would they compute the little endian in the xor instruction? 67452301 is different when looked independently against 1234567 in hexadecimal. I thought Intel just stored the information in little endian, not compute bitwise operators in that order. The numbers arent the same. Can you shine a light on this for me?

Comment: The disassembler displayed `1234567` for you, but in reality that's stored and used as byte sequence `67 45 23 01`. Alternatively, you can convert all the other numbers. `1234` is then `34333231` and the result is `35107756` which will be stored in memory in little endian as byte sequence `56 77 10 35`.

Comment: @Jester so in reality the number in hex is 1234567 but the computer uses it as 67452301, correct? Its all the same, just different in how its displayed.

Comment: The computer uses it as `1234567` (for example if you add one to it) but when accessing memory it is stored as `67 45 23 01`. Technically, this xor operation is a read-modify-write. First the original value is loaded from memory assuming little endian format, thus your ascii `1234` will be interpreted as `34333231`. Then the xor will be performed, giving `35107756` and finally that will be written into memory in little endian as byte sequence `56 77 10 35`.

Comment: @Jester Wait then why does the hex dump display the 1234 as 31323334 (big endian)? I was guessing it was the disassembler helping me out, which I believe it is but when I goto an xor calculator and type in 31323334 (as it is in the hex dump) xor 67452301 I get 56771035. But when I type in 34333231 xor 67452301 I dont get the correct answer. Why is this?

Comment: Depends on how your hex dump tool works. Normally that prints numbers as space separated byte sequences which is not equal to the numeric interpretation. `1234` ascii string has bytes `31 32 33 34` in memory but that's the number `34333231` in little-endian.

Comment: @Jester but why is it that you have to keep the number 1234 in big endian and then 1234567 in little endian? Why arent they both in little endian?

Comment: The ASCII representation is for humans to read and the memory content is for the CPU to read and our program have to translate between the endianess.

Comment: `1234` in your example is not a number, it's a string and strings are stored left-to-right.